# What is the substitute of flushall in code blocks IDE?

Tags: c

This is my code which runs perfectly well in Turbo C but not in code blocks. The only problem i'm facing is with flushall(). How can i overcome this problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int extractDigits(unsigned long int num, int *index, int *digits)
{
    if (num)
    {
        digits[*index] = num % 10;
        *index = *index + 1;
        extractDigits(num / 10, index, digits);
    }
    return(*index);
}
int main()
{
    int x=0,j,i,index=0,digit,digits[32];
    unsigned long int n1,n2,temp,num,count=0;
    printf("\n Enter lower value n1 : ");
    if(!scanf("%lu",&n1))
        x=1;
    flushall();
    printf("\n Enter higher value n2 : ");
    if(!scanf("%lu",&n2))
        x=1;
    flushall();
    printf("\n Enter the digit you wish to count : ");
    if(!scanf("%d",&digit))
        x=1;
    flushall();
    if(n1>n2||x)
    {
a:printf("\n Invalid Input\n");
  goto z;
    }
    if(n1<0||n1>150000||n2<0||n2>150000)
        goto a;
    if(!n1)
        count++;
    for(temp=n1;temp<=n2;temp++)
    {
        num=temp;
        i=extractDigits(num, &index, digits);
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(digits[j]==digit)
                count++;
        }
        index=0;
    }
    printf("\n Count : %lu \n",count);
z:return 0;
```

If I don't use flushall() then I'm unable to run the test conditions for invalid input. What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: You should format your code better, it's incredible hard to read when you don't indent properly.

Comment: I rather doubt there is a substitute and I question the practice of using it in the first place. According to some documentation I found here - http://www.ousob.com/ng/turboc/ng2245a.php - it flushes all open files. That's hardly good practice in a multithreaded world. Have you tried flushing the files you actually have open?

Comment: 1) `fflush(stdin);` (note : non portable) 2) `while('\n' != fgetc(stdin));`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/

I didn't find flushall(), may be the compile is diffent.

There is `fflush`. Maybe you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a matter of IDE, but of compiler and most importantly of C standard libraries.

C99 and Posix conforming libraries have [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) which is documented as:

> int fflush(FILE* stream);
>
> If the stream argument is NULL, fflush() flushes all open output
>          streams.

So just call

```
    fflush(NULL);
```

when you want to flush all output streams (which is what I guess your non-standard `fflushall` is doing).

Notice that a common habit is to *end*, not start, with `\n`  the [printf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) format string, since `stdout` is often line buffered.